# bcp queryout xml format file encoding utf-8 xml file validation fail

Tags: sql, xml, utf-8, encode, bcp

I have to generate xml file for the format of encoding="UTF-8. I used bcp queryout. xml file was generating. But my issue was the xml file validation fail. could any one help me to resolve this? This is my code.

```
 DECLARE @xmlBody AS VARCHAR(MAX)= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'+ CAST(@xmlStr  AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 


       INSERT INTO  [dbo].[MasterXml]   
           ([PurchaseOrderID] ,[Code])          
        values (@PurchaseOrderID, @xmlBody)                         
        Declare @command varchar(8000)          

        SET @command= 'bcp "SELECT TOP 1 [Code] from  [tec_Dev].[dbo].[MasterXml] where PurchaseOrderID='+          
        CAST( @PurchaseOrderID As varchar(20))+'" queryout '            
         +@uploadFolder + CAST(@PurchaseOrderID AS varchar(20))+'.xml' +' -T -N -w -c -C65001'

    print @command

EXEC xp_cmdshell @command
```

Comment: maybe @xmlStr is somehow wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found  solution

```
 +@uploadFolder + CAST(@PurchaseOrderID AS varchar(20))+'.xml' +' -T -N -w -c -C65001'
```

I remove the  -w from the code. then it works. But it works only for 
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2-CU6) (KB4019094) - 12.0.5553.0 (X64).

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3136780/utf-8-encoding-support-for-the-bcp-utility-and-bulk-insert-transact-sq

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code I get this is `[sql-server]`...

SQL-Server's `VARCHAR`-type is *1-byte-encoded extended ASCII* (depending on the associated `COLLATION`) and not `UTF-8`...

Whenever SQL-Server is talking about **unicode** it is the native `NVARCHAR` or `NCHAR` type, which is a *2-byte-encoded string* (`UCS-2` actually).

Furthermore you are stating some switches

- `-N`: Use the native types in any case, use **unicode** for characters.
- `-w`: Explicit switch to use **unicode**
- `-C`: with page 65001 (`utf-8`), while the documentation explicitly tells you, that [this codepage is not supported!](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802(v=sql.110).aspx).

If the rest is okay, your code should place a file on disk which is *2-byte-unicode*, but is yelling: "I'm UTF-8!". Try the same with `UTF-16` in the XML's declaration. Alternatively you can use any other tool to convert SQL-Server's output to the encoding of your choice.

I'd tend to C#: Read the XML directly into a .NET-string (always unicode!) from SQL-Server (no BCP at all) and write the .Net-string to a file using the proper encoding.

### UPDATE

At the given link ([BCP documentation for SQL Server 2014](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802(v=sql.120).aspx)) there is still

> ** Important ** SQL Server does not support code page 65001 (UTF-8 encoding).

But for version 2016+ you can find this:

> Versions prior to version 13 ( SQL Server 2016 (13.x)) do not support
>   code page 65001 (UTF-8 encoding). Versions beginning with 13 can
>   import UTF-8 encoding to earlier versions of SQL Server.

But 2014-SP2 adds this to v2014 actually ([KB-Article 3136780](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3136780)). So the documentation is not covering this backward enhancement.

It should work to export UTF-8 using this combination without the `-N -w`:

```
-c -C65001
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I found solution   for    Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2-CU6) (KB4019094) - 12.0.5553.0 (X64)  it works with removing  '-w' . https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3136780/utf-8-encoding-support-for-the-bcp-utility-and-bulk-insert-transact-sq

Comment: @ChamathViduranga Thx, updated my answer to reflect this. For your next question it would help, to state the RDBMS and the version...