# Output XML Files with encoding UTF-8 using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, encoding, bcp

I have a query that generates XML files and loads them to FTP with `<?xml version="1.0"?>`.

I need to switch encoding to UTF-8 as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

I can do it manually in the text editor. But cannot do it in SQL Server.

I also read this article but that did not contribute in finding solution for the issue.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/create-instances-of-xml-data

[image]

[image]

My code:

```
USE [Audit_DBA]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- to call the procedure use the code below but assign your own path: 
-- EXEC [Audit_DBA].[dbo].[StateAndLocalAward_ToXML] 'C:\NLP\Test\NewFolder'

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[StateAndLocalAward_ToXML_VC]
    @FileDestinationDir VARCHAR(2000)
AS 
    DECLARE  @FilePath VARCHAR(4000)

    DECLARE @SQLStr VARCHAR(8000),
            @Cmd VARCHAR(1000),
            @Ret INT

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM InputTemp.SYS.TABLES WHERE NAME = 'StateAndLocalAward_output') 
       DROP TABLE InputTemp.dbo.StateAndLocalAward_output;

    ;WITH CTE_StateAndLocalAward_output AS 
    (
        SELECT TOP 200
            sc.stateContractId,
            ca.OnviaId AS [Reference], --AS OnviaID,
            ca.contractTitle AS [Title], 
            nigp.NIGPCodeTx AS [NIPGCode],
            nigp.NIGPDescriptionLongTx AS [NIPGDescription],
            ca.Description,
            vm.parentName AS [VendorName],
            offering.offeringTx AS [PrimaryOffering],
            ca.StartDate,
            ca.AwardDt
        FROM 
            ISCore.dbo.StateContract sc WITH (NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN 
            ISCore.dbo.ContractAward ca WITH (NOLOCK) ON sc.contractAwardId = ca.contractAwardID
        INNER JOIN 
            ISLibrary.dbo.VendorMaster vm WITH (NOLOCK) ON ca.vendorId = vm.vendorID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            ISCore.dbo.CompanyProfile cp WITH (NOLOCK) ON ca.vendorId = cp.vendorId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            ISCore.dbo.Offering offering WITH (NOLOCK) ON ca.offeringID = offering.offeringID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            ISCore.dbo.NIGPSrvc nigp WITH (NOLOCK) ON ca.NIGPCode = nigp.NIGPCodeTx
        WHERE 
            vm.showUnverified = 1 AND sc.stateContractId = -- 464482 stateContractId
            AND StartDate >= DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE())
    )
    SELECT 
        *
    INTO 
        InputTemp.dbo.StateAndLocalAward_output 
    FROM 
        CTE_StateAndLocalAward_output;

    --select * from InputTemp.dbo.StateAndLocalAward_output

    DECLARE @StateContractId INT;
    --DECLARE @xml XML;

    DECLARE Cur_StateAndLocalAward_StateContractId CURSOR FOR
        SELECT StateContractId
        FROM inputtemp.dbo.StateAndLocalAward_output t1 WITH (NOLOCK)

    OPEN Cur_StateAndLocalAward_StateContractId;

    FETCH NEXT FROM Cur_StateAndLocalAward_StateContractId INTO @StateContractId -- @xml;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
            @SQLStr = 'SELECT Body.[Reference], Body.[Title], Body.[NIPGCode], Body.[NIPGDescription], Body.[Description], Body.[VendorName], Body.[PrimaryOffering] FROM InputTemp.dbo.StateAndLocalAward_output AS Body where StateContractId = ''' + str(@StateContractId) + ''' FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS;'

        --SELECT N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' 
        SELECT
            CAST((SELECT N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' + (@SQLSTr)) as varchar(8000) /*as XML*/) as SQLStr 

        -- select CAST((SELECT N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' + 
        --  (@SQLSTr)) as XML) as SQLStr
```

If I run this code instead of the same above but cast as `XML type`, I get an error:

> Msg 9402, Level 16, State 1, Procedure StateAndLocalAward_ToXML, Line 86 [Batch Start Line 10]
>   XML parsing: line 1, character 38, unable to switch the encoding

```
select @FilePath = @FileDestinationDir+'\NewFolder'+ltrim(rtrim(str(@StateContractId)))+'.xml' 
select @Cmd = ' bcp " ' + @SQLStr + '" queryout '+@FilePath+' -w -r "" -T -S ' +@@ServerName 
exec  @Ret = master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @Cmd 
FETCH NEXT FROM Cur_StateAndLocalAward_StateContractId INTO @StateContractId -- @xml;
END
CLOSE Cur_StateAndLocalAward_StateContractId;
DEALLOCATE Cur_StateAndLocalAward_StateContractId;
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyXMLTest]
@FileDestinationDir VARCHAR(2000)

-- to call procedure specify your own file path 
-- EXEC [Audit_DBA].[dbo].[MyXMLTest] 'E:\NLP\GovwinIQ_Ontology\NewFolder'

AS 

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

IF OBJECT_ID (N'InputTemp.dbo.XMLTest', N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE InputTemp.dbo.XMLTest;

CREATE TABLE InputTemp.dbo.XMLTest

(
[Id] INT NOT NULL,
[FirstName] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
[LastName] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
[Address] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO InputTemp.dbo.XMLTest ([Id], [FirstName], [LastName], [Address])
VALUES (12, 'Zhuk', 'Termik', '123 Gam Str, Boston, NY');

--SELECT * FROM InputTemp.dbo.XMLTest

DECLARE @FilePath VARCHAR(4000)

DECLARE @SQLStr NVARCHAR(4000),
        @Cmd NVARCHAR(4000),
        @Ret INT

DECLARE @Id INT;

SELECT @Id = 12;

SELECT @SQLStr = 
'SELECT N''<?xml version=''''1.0'''' encoding=''''UTF-8''''?>'' + (SELECT CAST((SELECT [Id], [FirstName], [LastName], [Address] FROM InputTemp.dbo.XMLTest AS Body WHERE Id = '''  + str(@Id) + ''' FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)))'

SELECT @SQLStr AS SQLStr

SELECT @FilePath = @FileDestinationDir+'\NewFolder'+ltrim(rtrim(str(@Id)))+'.xml' 

SELECT @Cmd = ' bcp " ' + @SQLStr + '" queryout '+@FilePath+' -c  -C65001 -r "" -T -S ' +@@ServerName 

EXEC @Ret = master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @Cmd 

IF OBJECT_ID (N'InputTemp.dbo.XMLTest', N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE InputTemp.dbo.XMLTest;

GO
```

Answer (score 3):

There are some things to know:

- SQL Server **does not support export via BCP to UTF-8 before version 2016 (and 2014 with SP2)**.
- One cannot add the xml-declaration (`<?xml blah ?>`) to a native SQL-Server XML typed variable or column. This will either fail ("...switch the encoding") or the xml-declaration will disappear.
- You can add the xml-declaration on string level to an xml casted to `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. But you cannot re-cast (re-convert) this to an XML without failing or losing the declaration.
- Internally SQL-Server keeps any XML as `UCS-2` (very close to `UTF-16`) in any case.
- SQL-Servers **`VARCHAR` (`CHAR`) type is not `utf-8`** but extended ASCII (depending on a `COLLATION`)
- on string level you can write literally anything into the xml-declaration (as you can creat something, which looks like XML, but is not well-formed. This is just an unchecked string.
- The encoding stated in the xml-declaration is important **only to mark the actual file encoding when written to a disk or when handled as byte stream**.
- You can write `encoding="x"` and store the file with an encoding of y - but you shouldn't.
- SQL-Server will cast a string with an `utf-8` declaration to XML when it is `VARCHAR` and it will cast a string with `utf-16` when it is `NVARCHAR`, but you cannot cross this ([Read this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41505440/5089204)). Other encodings very likely lead to *cannot switch the encoding* error.

About your code

- You should change `@SQLStr` and `@cmd` to `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, othewise you might get in troubles with non-plain-latin characters.
- As you are using a `CURSOR`, you should fill an XML-typed variable with the result of your statement, cast this to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and add the declaration to this string. Do not cast the result back to XML.
- Read the `BCP` docs. Stating `-w` will write `unicode` (*wide*), which is not `utf-8` (what you write into the declaration has no effect here).

### Hint:

[Read this related answer, showing utf-8 export with BCP on SQL-Server 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49625209/5089204)

Comment: Thanks so much Shnugo. I did change my code as per your recommendation - SQLStr nvarchar(max) and Cmd nvarchar(4000) on the variable declaration level and I also needed to switch Database Compatibility level to 2016. And the generated XML files switch encoding to UTF-8 when I opened them in Notepad++ and looked up for Encoding. But when I opened the XML files in Internet Explorer the XML displayed <?xml version="1.0"?> and not  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Comment: Is there any way to literally specify <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  before the XML file structure begins?

Comment: @enigma6205, No SQL Server will not do this for you. But you can easily concatenate the casted XML with any string you want. Use `SET @content=N'<?xml whatever ?>' + CAST(@theXml AS NVARCHAR(MAX))` and write this out.